# For Angular how do I get a function to call on load

Tags: javascript, angular

For the company, I am working for, we have a form that has a summary page. The summary page encompasses all the data that was added on the form. The form is large and users may complete the form weeks before they started the form.

On the summary page, I created a function that throws an error if the date that was entered in the form is invalid.

summary.component.ts:

```
@HostListener('window:load', ['$event'])
  isRequestedTATValid(event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.app_state.pages.length; i++) {
      const currentPage = this.app_state.pages[i];

      const requestedTATDate = moment(currentPage.data.requestedDueDate, ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS']).format('M/D/YYYY hh:mm a\'');
      const minimumDateTime = moment(this.todaysDate, ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS']).add(4, 'hours').format('M/D/YYYY hh:mm a\'');

      if (requestedTATDate < minimumDateTime) {
        // Currently using toastr but would like for text to be red if 
        // there is an error
        this.toastr.error("Please provide a valid time for Desired TAT");
      }
    }
  }
```

summary.component.html

```
<div (load)="isRequestedTATValid($event)" class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <h1 class="mb-3">Summary</h1>
</div>
```

By the way, I am a mobile developer, so all and web is kinda new to me.

This is what I would like to know. When screen load, based on the code I have, will the function be called? How can I disable the submit button on the form if there is an error? How can I get the text to be red when there is an error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello @darron, what is your facing issue ? Function `isRequestedTATValid` is called or not ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know will the screen successfully call this function on load and I would like to know how to get the text of the date to be red if an error appears? I am a mobile developer so this is new to me. Also there is a submit button on the summary page. I want to disable that button if there is an error.

Comment: You do not want to use `@HostListener('window:load', ['$event'])` for this. Instead use implement interface `OnInit` (method `ngOnInit`) in your component. You can make additional server side requests in there as well if you need to.

Comment: `"How can I disable the submit button on the form if there is an error?"` ← Different question but do a search on this. There are different ways to create your form (see template vs reactive forms) and it is easy to hook the `[disabled]` attribute of a `button` to some form validator check.

Comment: In short do a little more research, most of your questions can be answered with a bit of searching as they have been asked many times before. If you still need help ask a *specific* question with an [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your help!